# First usage of Outworlder in science fiction

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

I'm currently rereading **Come hunt an Earthman** by Philip E High (published in 1973)

I've noticed throughout the book that the term "**outworlder**" is used to describe an alien.
I know I've saw this term used occasionally (but very rarely) in what are deemed Golden Age SF books.

My question is:- What's the first usage of outworlder in a Science Fiction story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earliest citation for the word *outworlder* (defined as "someone from an outworld; an alien; an outsider") in [The Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction](https://sfdictionary.com/view/448/outworlder) is from ["A Matter of Size"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47093), a novella by [Harry Bates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Bates_(writer)) in [*Astounding Stories*, **April 1934**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57372+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v13n02_1934-04_dtsg0318-LennyS/page/n39/mode/2up):

> The out-worlder smiled. He sat on a chair and removed one sandal, exposing a foot such as no man on Earth had ever yet possessed. The big toe was very large, and was flanked by another only a little bit smaller. The three outer toes were vestigial. Here was the foot of the human race, thousands of years in the future.

The [HDSF](https://sfdictionary.com/) has even older citations for the related word *outworld* as a [noun](https://sfdictionary.com/view/1201/outworld) or an [adjective](https://sfdictionary.com/view/1074/outworld).